# Как тестировать методы класса работающие с внешним окружением?

Tags: юнит-тесты, java, mockup

Например, у класса есть public метод, которому передаётся путь к файлу. В методе файл открывается и обрабатывается. Результат обработки сохраняется в атрибут класса.

Как пишутся unit-тесты в таких случаях?

Читал про monkey-патчинг, но как я понял в Java этот метод не работает. Можно было бы вынести открытие файла в отдельный метод, а обработчику файла отдавать объект с уже открытым файлом, но есть ли способ, который бы позволил не переписывать код тестируемой программы под тесты.

Comment: вопрос слишком абстрактый... что именно тебе надо протестировать?

Comment: В методе открывается файл, мне нужно подставить свои данные в этот файл. Если начать менять исходный код программы, то можно использовать mock-объекты. Но можно ли протестировать без изменения кода самой программы?

Comment: а что мешает передать путь к своему файлу на время тестов?

Comment: Думал есть способ заменить файл на stub или mock, чтобы потом не таскать вместе с тестами еще и просто файл. К тому же, этот файл будет меняться от теста к тесту.

Answer (score 1):

можно считывать значение приватной переменной с помощью reflection, а можно с помощью вложеных классов:

```
public class ObjectToTest
{
    private Object testField = null ;

    public void readFile ( File path )
    {
        this.testField = readFileImpl ( path ) ;
    }

    private Object readFileImpl ( File path )
    {
        // TODO: implement read file logic
        return null ;
    }

    public class TestPrivateField extends TestCase
    {
        @ Test
        public void testImpl ()
        {
            ObjectToTest objectToTest = new ObjectToTest () ;
            objectToTest.readFile ( new File ( "<path to file to process>" ) ) ;

            assertEquals ( "<expected result>", testField ) ;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: млин, способ понятный, непонятно - зачем? что бы проверить или путь тот который иы указал в конфиге??))

Comment: Проблема не в том чтобы получить доступ к приватной переменной, а в том чтобы переопределить стандартный класс на время выполнения теста.

Comment: сделать extend =)

Comment: > млин, способ понятный, непонятно - зачем?

потому что:   
а) это самый просто и эффективный вариант доступа к приватным свойствам класса  
б) не требует изменений тестируемого класса

Comment: > Проблема не в том чтобы получить доступ к приватной переменной, а в том чтобы переопределить стандартный класс на время выполнения теста.

вы спросили я ответил. ваш производит действия над данными в файле и в результате меняется состояние вашего класса. суть вашего теста должна быть следующей: создать файл с нужным вам содержимым. вызвать метод. проверить состояние обьекта

Comment: Mock можно применить, но придется разбивать метод на несколько. Хотел этого избежать.